# Why do I have to trigger a click event twice to get the proper dataLayer to fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid, google-datalayer

**Context**

I am attempting to push events to the data layer on a Shopify site. I'm utilizing a liquid file that combines liquid and JS code to extract appropriate data from the site to push to the data layer. All of the events are firing properly with the exception of the "Remove from Cart" event.

**Issue Description**

The initial issue was that the "Remove from Cart" event data layer push never fired because the cart page reloaded to show the updated cart prior to the push.

With the code below, I am now able to get the "Remove from Cart" event to fire, **BUT it only fires on the 2nd click of the remove icon.**

**Question**

How do I get the "Remove from Cart" event push to fire on the initial click of the remove icon prior to the cart reload?

**JS/Liquid Helper File**

Removed unnecessary code for brevity.

```
if(!window.jQuery){
    var jqueryScript = document.createElement('script');
    jqueryScript.setAttribute('src','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js');
    document.head.appendChild(jqueryScript);
}

__DL__jQueryinterval = setInterval(function(){
    // wait for jQuery to load & run script after jQuery has loaded
    if(window.jQuery){
        
        /**********************
        * DYNAMIC DEPENDENCIES
        ***********************/

        __DL__ = {
            dynamicCart: true,  // if cart is dynamic (meaning no refresh on cart add) set to true
            debug: true, // if true, console messages will be displayed
            cart:  true,
            removeCart: true
        };

        customBindings = {
            cartTriggers: [],
            viewCart: [],
            removeCartTrigger: [],
        };

        /* DO NOT EDIT */
        defaultBindings = {
            //removeCartTrigger: ['[href*="/cart/change"]'],
            removeCartTrigger: ['.tests'],
        };

        // stitch bindings
        objectArray = customBindings;
        outputObject = __DL__;

        applyBindings = function(objectArray, outputObject){
            for (var x in objectArray) {
                var key = x;
                var objs = objectArray[x];
                values = [];
                if(objs.length > 0){
                    values.push(objs);
                    if(key in outputObject){
                        values.push(outputObject[key]);
                        outputObject[key] = values.join(", ");
                    }else{
                        outputObject[key] = values.join(", ");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        applyBindings(customBindings, __DL__);
        applyBindings(defaultBindings, __DL__);

        /**********************
        * DATALAYER SECTIONS
        ***********************/

                /** DATALAYER: Cart View
                * Fire anytime a user views their cart (non-dynamic) */
                {% if template contains 'cart' %}
                var cart = {
                    'products':[{% for line_item in cart.items %}{
                        'id'       : {{line_item.product_id | json}},
                        'sku'      : {{line_item.sku | json}},
                        'variant'  : {{line_item.variant_id | json}},
                        'name'     : {{line_item.title | json}},
                        'price'    : {{line_item.price | money_without_currency | remove: "," | json}},
                        'quantity' : {{line_item.quantity | json}}
                    },{% endfor %}],
                    'pageType' : 'Cart',
                    'event'    : 'Cart'
                };

                dataLayer.push(cart);

                if(__DL__.debug){
                    console.log("Cart"+" :"+JSON.stringify(cart, null, " "));
                }

                __DL__.cart = cart.products;

                $(__DL__.removeCartTrigger).on('click', function (event) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                       //const goTo = $(this).attr("data-href");  // store anchor href
                        // remove from cart
                        jQuery.getJSON("/cart", function (response) {
                            // get Json response
                            __DL__.removeCart = response;
                            var removeFromCart = {
                                'products': __DL__.removeCart.items.map(function (line_item) {
                                    return {
                                        'id'       : line_item.product_id,
                                        'sku'      : line_item.sku,
                                        'variant'  : line_item.variant_id,
                                        'name'     : line_item.title,
                                        'price'    : (line_item.price/100),
                                        'quantity' : line_item.quantity
                                    }
                                }),
                                'pageType' : 'Remove from Cart',
                                'event'    : 'Remove from Cart'
                            };
                            __DL__.removeCart = removeFromCart;

                            var cartIDs = [];
                            var removeIDs = [];
                            var removeCart = [];

                            // remove from cart logic
                            for(var i=__DL__.cart.length-1;i>=0;i--){var x=parseFloat(__DL__.cart[i].variant);cartIDs.push(x)}for(var i=__DL__.removeCart.products.length-1;i>=0;i--){var x=parseFloat(__DL__.removeCart.products[i].variant);removeIDs.push(x)}function arr_diff(b,c){var a=[],diff=[];for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){a[b[i]]=true}for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){if(a[c[i]]){delete a[c[i]]}else{a[c[i]]=true}}for(var k in a){diff.push(k)}return diff};var x=arr_diff(cartIDs,removeIDs)[0];for(var i=__DL__.cart.length-1;i>=0;i--){if(__DL__.cart[i].variant==x){removeCart.push(__DL__.cart[i])}}

                            dataLayer.push(removeCart);

                            if (__DL__.debug) {
                                console.log("Item Removed from Cart"+" :"+JSON.stringify(removeCart, null, " "));
                            }
                        });
                    }, 2000);
                });

                {% endif %}

                            /**********************
                            * DATALAYER EVENT BINDINGS
                            ***********************/

                            /** DATALAYER:
                            * Add to Cart / Dynamic Cart View
                            * Fire all pages trigger after all additional dataLayers have loaded. */

                            $(document).ready(function() {

                                /** DATALAYER: Cart */

                                // stage cart data
                                function mapJSONcartData(){
                                    jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function (response) {
                                        // get Json response
                                        __DL__.cart = response;
                                        var cart = {
                                            'products': __DL__.cart.items.map(function (line_item) {
                                                return {
                                                    'id'       : line_item.id,
                                                    'sku'      : line_item.sku,
                                                    'variant'  : line_item.variant_id,
                                                    'name'     : line_item.title,
                                                    'price'    : (line_item.price/100),
                                                    'quantity' : line_item.quantity
                                                }
                                            }),
                                            'pageType' : 'Cart',
                                            'event'    : 'Cart'
                                        };
                                        if(cart.products.length > 0){
                                            dataLayer.push(cart);
                                            if (__DL__.debug) {
                                                console.log("Cart"+" :"+JSON.stringify(cart, null, " "));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                viewcartfire = 0;

                                // view cart
                                $(__DL__.viewCart).on('click', function (event) {
                                    if(viewcartfire !== 1){
                                        viewcartfire = 1;
                                        // if dynamic cart is TRUE
                                        if (__DL__.dynamicCart) {
                                            cartCheck = setInterval(function () {
                                                // begin check interval
                                                if ($(__DL__.cartVisableSelector).length > 0) {
                                                    // check visible selectors
                                                    clearInterval(cartCheck);
                                                    mapJSONcartData();
                                                    $(__DL__.removeCartTrigger).on('click', function (event) {
                                                        // remove from cart
                                                        var link = $(this).attr("href");
                                                        jQuery.getJSON(link, function (response) {
                                                            // get Json response
                                                            __DL__.removeCart = response;
                                                            var removeFromCart = {
                                                                'products': __DL__.removeCart.items.map(function (line_item) {
                                                                    return {
                                                                        'id'       : line_item.id,
                                                                        'sku'      : line_item.sku,
                                                                        'variant'  : line_item.variant_id,
                                                                        'name'     : line_item.title,
                                                                        'price'    : (line_item.price/100),
                                                                        'quantity' : line_item.quantity
                                                                    }
                                                                }),
                                                                'pageType' : 'Remove from Cart',
                                                                'event'    : 'Remove from Cart'
                                                            };
                                                            dataLayer.push(removeFromCart);
                                                            if (__DL__.debug) {
                                                                console.log("Cart"+" :"+JSON.stringify(removeFromCart, null, " "));
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }, 500);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                // add to cart
                                jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function (response) {
                                    // get Json response
                                    __DL__.cart = response;
                                    var cart = {
                                        'products': __DL__.cart.items.map(function (line_item) {
                                            return {
                                                'id'       : line_item.id,
                                                'sku'      : line_item.sku,
                                                'variant'  : line_item.variant_id,
                                                'name'     : line_item.title,
                                                'price'    : (line_item.price/100),
                                                'quantity' : line_item.quantity
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                    __DL__.cart = cart;
                                    collection_cartIDs = [];
                                    collection_matchIDs = [];
                                    collection_addtocart = [];
                                    for (var i = __DL__.cart.products.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                        var x = parseFloat(__DL__.cart.products[i].variant);
                                        collection_cartIDs.push(x);
                                    }
                                });

                                function __DL__addtocart(){



                                    dataLayer.push(product, {
                                        'pageType' : 'Add to Cart',
                                        'event'    : 'Add to Cart'
                                    });

                                    if (__DL__.debug) {
                                        console.log("Add to Cart"+" :"+JSON.stringify(product, null, " "));
                                    }

                                    // if dynamic cart is TRUE
                                    if (__DL__.dynamicCart) {
                                        console.log("dynamic");
                                        var cartCheck = setInterval(function () {
                                            // begin check interval
                                            if ($(__DL__.cartVisableSelector).length > 0) {
                                                // check visible selectors
                                                clearInterval(cartCheck);
                                                mapJSONcartData();
                                                $(__DL__.removeCartTrigger).on('click', function (event) {
                                                    // remove from cart
                                                    var link = $(this).attr("href");
                                                    jQuery.getJSON(link, function (response) {
                                                        // get Json response
                                                        __DL__.removeCart = response;
                                                        var removeFromCart = {
                                                            'products': __DL__.removeCart.items.map(function (line_item) {
                                                                return {
                                                                    'id'       : line_item.id,
                                                                    'sku'      : line_item.sku,
                                                                    'variant'  : line_item.variant_id,
                                                                    'name'     : line_item.title,
                                                                    'price'    : (line_item.price/100),
                                                                    'quantity' : line_item.quantity
                                                                }
                                                            }),
                                                            'pageType' : 'Remove from Cart',
                                                            'event'    : 'Remove from Cart'
                                                        };
                                                        dataLayer.push(removeFromCart);
                                                        if (__DL__.debug) {
                                                            console.log("Cart"+" :"+JSON.stringify(removeFromCart, null, " "));
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }, 500);
                                    }
                                }

                                $(document).on('click', __DL__.cartTriggers, function() {
                                    __DL__addtocart();
                                });

                                }); // document ready
                            }
                        }, 500);
```

**Remove from Cart Link**

```
<a href="#" data-href="/cart/change?line=1&amp;quantity=0" class="tests cart-item__remove icon-fallback">
    <i class="icon icon--close" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
    <span class="icon-fallback__text">Remove</span>
</a>
```

**Initial Data Layer Push (1st Remove from Cart Link Click)**

```
{
  event: "Cart",
  gtm: {uniqueEventId: XXX, start: XXXXXXX},
  logState: "Logged Out",
  firstLog: false,
  customerEmail: null,
  timestamp: 1626795802651,
  currency: "USD",
  pageType: "Cart",
  products: [
    {
      id: XXXX,
      sku: "XXX",
      variant: XXX,
      name: "XXXX",
      price: 20,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ],
  necessaryTags: true,
  performanceTags: true,
  functionalTags: true,
  targettingTags: true
}
```

**Second Data Layer Push (2nd Remove from Cart Link Click)**

```
{
  event: "Remove from Cart",
  gtm: {uniqueEventId: XXX, start: XXXXXX},
  logState: "Logged Out",
  firstLog: false,
  timestamp: 1626796193806,
  currency: "USD",
  pageType: "Remove from Cart",
  products: [
    {
      id: XXXX,
      sku: "XXX",
      variant: XXX,
      name: "XXXX",
      price: 20,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ],
  necessaryTags: true,
  performanceTags: false,
  functionalTags: false,
  targettingTags: false
}
```

I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: "Brevity"... I'm not sure that's what qualifies as "brief".

Comment: Perhaps not. But, it's brief in comparison to the complete file. I often come across questions where people are asking for more complete code, so I erred on that side rather than too little.

Comment: Right... but I don't think we need "landing page cookie", among numerous other blocks of code...

Comment: I pulled out more unnecessary code.

Comment: If the cart reload event is dependant on another action such add, delete or update cart items, you should separate it into a function and call it after finishing one of those actions instead binding it as event. unless you need this event to trigger something else. BTW i did not a comprehensive read about  all the code (too much code), you can just add the code related to current concerns which would be remove cart and cart reload. Also we don't need all the actions inside them, a comment suck // do stuff is enough instead copying all product or cart properties with it's getters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there's a 3rd Party Shopify app that's hijacking the cart form submit event and forcing a reload of the cart page. While this doesn't solve my problem, it does answer the question in this post.